# Rails Api for mobile apps: how to fix CORS just for api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rack

I'm designing a suite of api for my Rails website. I already write the api and they works on local, i testes them with RSpec and with OSX app "Rested".

Now I must handle the "CORS": all my api at the moment are only "GET" api, no post or patch.

I need to access my api from apps and from another domain that have to handle a content feed.

I'm not so familiar with CORS, I read that the best option is to use "Rack Cors Gem".

Rack-cors docs suggest to put this in application.rb

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # ...

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end

  end
end
```

I'm afraid about security: I read something but I cannot understand why is dangerous to use '*'

In my case the api are under www.example.com/api/v1

Can I modify the rack-cors configuration just add cors to my api in this way?

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # ...

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '\api\v1', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :options]
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with the Rack::Cors gem. This is easy enough to do just in Rails, I think this is a case of "gem-itis". Yes, you're going to have to understand a bit about what CORS actually does to make sure you're doing what you want -- you're going to have to do that either way, with or without a gem. CORS is not too complicated, it will pay to read about it, perhaps here: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

If I understand right, you don't want to add CORS headers to *every* action (allowing cross-domain javascript access to every action), but just to certain actions?  Which ones, how will they be identified?

Let's say you only have one action, `index` in WidgetController that you want to add CORS to, *and* you only want to add it to 'json' type requests, not to html requests. Here's how you might do that. Add to your WidgetController code (at ./app/controllers/widget_controller.rb):

```
 before_filter :add_cors_to_json, :only => :index

 protected def add_cors_to_json
   if request.format == "application/json"
     # "*" to allow for any domain, or specify certain domains
     response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
   end
 end
```

I don't think the Rack::CORS gem is giving you anything -- you still need to understand what's going on to make it do what you want, but now you need to understand the Rack::CORS gem too. Just do it in Rails.

Comment: GooD to know. So I can modify the header just for for the api controller. I will read the link you provide. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, you can use the following way:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '/api/v1/*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :options]
  end
end
```